# How contextual bandit use single model out put q-value for each arm?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, reinforcement-learning

I've been studying Thompson Sampling and one of the bottleneck is that when recommending 100 items to users, each item has `beta distribution` thus need to select random value from 100 different distribution which is very computationally heavy.

From "Mastering RL with Python by Enes Bilgin" it says that computation burden can be mitigated by use of contextual bandit.

I've read it multiple times however cannot fully understand. From what I've read, function approximation for context doesn't seem to reduce computation burden however function approximation for action does however I can't understand how.

can someone explain how contextual bandit outputs multiple q-values for multiple items?

Comment: have you find any answer?